# Add the row count in an HTML table using protractor - non Angular

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I am trying to count the rows of the table and below is the HTML

```html
<tr id="resultsRepeaterGrid">
 <tr id="tableheader"></tr>
  <tr id="Data list1_datarow class = row">
    <div style>row 1</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Data list2_datarow class= altrow">
    <div style>row 2</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Data list3_datarow class = row">
    <div style>row 1</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

I want to get the total count rows of the table, discarding table header and expanded row. I had tried the code below:

```js
searchRes = element(by.id('resultsRepeaterGrid')); //grid to be displayed
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(searchRes), 30000);
var searchResCount = element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid > tr:not(.tableheader)'));
expect(searchResCount.count()).toEqual(3);
```

But I am getting Expected 0 to equal 3. Now I have thought of just getting the total of row and altrow classes and the code is below:

```js
 element.all(by.css('.row')).count().then(function (rowCount) {
            element.all(by.css('.altrow')).count().then(function (altRowCount) {
                expect(rowCount + altRowCount).toEqual(1);
            })
        });
```

I get an error of stale element. I am not sure now how to get the count of the row itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count `tr` elements having either `class="row"` or `class="altrow"`:

```
#resultsRepeaterGrid tr[class="row"],tr[class="altrow"]
```

Comment: I removed the > and now it says Expected 57 to equal 3 :(.

Comment: I tried the updated answer and that is the one that I was aiming to do earlier, I was unsure about the syntax to use :) Thanks so much @alecxe it works!